# How do i make this non-interactive?

Tags: unix, hadoop, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, docker

I am trying to install pseudo-distributed hadoop installation. In that, i am installing ssh for passwordless authentication. I am running it from inside a docker file.

```
   RUN /usr/bin/sudo apt-get install -y openssh-server openssh-client
   WORKDIR /home/hadoop_admin
   RUN mkdir /home/hadoop_admin/.ssh
   RUN chmod 700 /home/hadoop_admin/.ssh
   RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
   RUN cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When i start ssh service, it asks for yes/no like the below. I want to make it yes always.

```
  The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
  ECDSA key fingerprint is [long hexa key value]
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/125324/how-can-i-avoid-sshs-host-verification-for-known-hosts

Answer (score 0):

This post has several considerations.

1) What is exactly the command that you are executing, so this error is raised ?Because it recalls me that is a ssh client trying to access to the ssh server. If so, you can add this parameter to the ssh client to avoid the error ... but it has security considerations.

```
echo 'Host * StrictHostKeyChecking no' >> ~/.ssh/config
```

2) You can use a docker base image that has, among many other things,  already the SSH server configured http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/

3) For the ssh client that is trying to connect to the server, you could auto-populate known_host before connecting via ssh

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa localhost >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```

4) If you are using docker containers, you should not need to SSH to the containers. If you SSH need to manage the containers it is recommended to  use [nsenter](http://blog.docker.com/tag/nsenter/) or any other alternative.